# Spotify application requests authorization

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, access-token, spotify

I am trying to get 'access token' from Spotify with the following code.

```
var encoded = btoa(client_id+':'+client_secret);
function myOnClick() {
   console.log('clikced!');
   $.ajax({
   url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
        grant_type : "client_credentials",
       'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   headers: {
       Authorization: 'Basic ' + encoded
   },
   dataType: 'json'
   }).always((data)=> console.log(data));
   }
```

However I keep getting errors:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

and

> readyState: 0, status: 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arielle from Spotify here.

Looks like you're using the Client Credentials Flow, which is one of 3 Authentication flows you can use with the Spotify API. (You can check out all 3 [here](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/))

Client Credentials is meant for server-side use only, and **should not be used on the front-end**, as it requires a client secret which you shouldn't be exposing!

You should use the **Implicit Grant** flow, which is made for use in the browser, instead. It's easy to get up and running, too!

```
// Get the hash of the url
const hash = window.location.hash
.substring(1)
.split('&')
.reduce(function (initial, item) {
  if (item) {
    var parts = item.split('=');
    initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
  }
  return initial;
}, {});
window.location.hash = '';

// Set token
let _token = hash.access_token;

const authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

// Replace with your app's client ID, redirect URI and desired scopes
const clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8888';
const scopes = [
  'user-read-birthdate',
  'user-read-email',
  'user-read-private'
];

// If there is no token, redirect to Spotify authorization
if (!_token) {
  window.location = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join('%20')}&response_type=token`;
}
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/arirawr/f08a1e17db3a1f65ada2c17592757049

And here's an example on Glitch, that you can "Remix" to make a copy and start making your app: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spotify-implicit-grant

Hope that helps - happy hacking! ‍

Comment: Hi Arielle, Thanks for the Answer. How about Angular can I use 'Client Credentials Flow' in Angular? I receive errors with this type of Authorization in Angular too.

Comment: Hi! Angular is a front-end Javascript framework so you will see the same problems and the Client Credentials flow **should not be used**. Node.js is Javascript on the server/back-end - you **would** be able to use client credentials there (here's an example, you can see the calls in `server.js` which is the back-end: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spotify-client-credentials).

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await axios({
  url: this.apiLoginUrl,
  method: 'post',
  data: "grant_type=client_credentials",
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(this.clientId + ":" + this.clientSecret).toString('base64')}`,
  },
});
```